# Как изменить определить id товара?

Tags: php, массивы, api

Имеется массив 
Данные с API

```
1 => A
2 => Г
3 => Е
4 => В
5 => Д
```

и записи в бд

```
31 => По смыслу относится к Д
14 => По смыслу относится к Е
22 => По смыслу относится к В
67 => По смыслу относится к А
88 => По смыслу относится к Г
```

Как определить что Г будет 2 (данные с api). Т.е. 88 заменить на 2 и наоборот.
общий у них только смысл, нет одинаковых ячеек.

Comment: Нужны реальные примеры данных, чтобы выявить, по какому критерию можно соотносить друг с другом строки из БД со строками из API. Никакого универсального алгоритма для выявления "схожего смысла строк" не существует.

Comment: Я думаю, что определить это сможет только экстрасенс :).